# How to use mailed .class files in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

So a friend of mine told me I could mail my java projects to myself (the .class files) and then just put them into my workspace (yes I know about github, but having trouble with it, looking into it), though when I paste them into my workspace in the correct package, the code does not change.

Even making an entire new package (which would be required since I mailed 2 projects, from which only one was on my primary computer) did not help, as the package remains empty.

Yes I've tried the import option, didn't work (yes I'm fairly new to eclipse)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why not just copy the source?  Is there a reason why you are using the .class files? Because, your actual classes are in the .java files.  .class files are the output/preliminary output for your application.  You can reverse the .class into code but I'm confused why you would want the .class to mail yourself a project...

Comment: if you really want to work with the .class file: create a jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .class files are binary executables that are compiled from the .java files. If you want to transfer an entire Eclipse project from one computer to another, you could zip the project from the top-level in your Eclipse workspace, email it, unzip it on the target computer, and then import it as an existing project into Eclipse. You can unzip it anywhere, but you might prefer to put the project into the Eclipse workspace on the target computer as a good convention.

Note: I would recommend cleaning the project before zipping it so that you *don't* transfer the .class files that are going to be rebuilt anyway. That will make the zip archive smaller.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* mail Java projects to yourself, but you want to send the *source* (.java) files to yourself. The .class files contain compiled [byte-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode) and are generated from the source. Zip up the entire project folder and email it to yourself or place it on a thumb drive.